# Jquerymobile: registering events within pageinit?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm writing a simple mobile web site using JQuery Mobile.
I wrote this code to handle clicks on anchors pointing to bookmarks within the page.

I put the code within a function and call the function from within the  section in the . Here is the code:

```
function initPage() {

        // Anchor links handling.
        $(document).on('vclick', 'a[href^=#][href!=#]', function() {
            location.hash = $(this).attr('href');
            return false;
        });
}
```

Here is my HTML fragment calling the code:

```
<html>
<head>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
   initPage();        
</script>
...
```

My code works fine, but I have a doubt, so here comes my question: should I wrap my code with $(document).on('pageinit')? Like this:

```
function initPage() {
    $(document).on('pageinit', function(){
        // Anchor links handling.
        $(document).on('vclick', 'a[href^=#][href!=#]', function() {
            location.hash = $(this).attr('href');
            return false;
        });
    });
}
```

I am not sure whether do I need to do that for stuff that register an event, like vclick on specific elements.

Thanks for support.

Comment: it depends, are you using _multi-page_ or _single page_ model? are you using jQM Ajax navigation?

Comment: I am using only single page model. Also, I am using Ajax navigation, except for specific links which I exclude with data-ajax=false. Regarding my question, please let me clarify that the anchor links handling function is only to handle some links within pages whose href point to bookmark anchors within that same page. The handler seems to work fine, but just I'm not sure whether I have to encapsulate it within the document.on(pageinit) block...